# Why does my truck turn off

Tags: ford, battery, f-250

Hi I have a 2000 F250 truck and I am experiencing difficulties keeping it started . So my question is when i jump it, it's fine as it's in park but when I go to put it in gear it shuts off? Or when I remove cables it does the samething? Does anyone have any advice or knowledge of this kinda issue?

Comment: You're saying that when you remove the jumper cables (after starting it), the engine immediately dies?  Do you have a volt meter to check the voltage?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your battery is dead. With the jumper on there, there's enough power to run the vehicle, but once removed, there's no power (or rather *enough power*) from the battery to energize the alternator, so the vehicle dies. Take the battery to a parts shop and get it tested not only for voltage, but load as well. If the battery is good, completely charge it.

You need to check the output of the alternator, but can only do that with a fresh or completely charged battery. It may be your battery is good, but with it being completely depleted and the alternator not being able to charge it, the truck dies.

Comment: Your battery could also have a bad cell which would prevent it from ever being charged again.

Comment: You can bench test an alternator and most parts stores will do that for free.